# c# a MessageBox prompt with a long input message will make buttons inaccessible

Tags: c#, winforms, button, prompt, messagebox

Using MessageBox.Show with buttons and a long input message will result in the buttons not actually being accessible, due to being off screen. The default message box has no way to resize, or to scroll down, which means when that happens there is no real way to hit the 'yes' button in the messagebox. Is there a way to ensure the buttons are accessible? Whether by making the MessageBox resizable, scrollable, truncate the message according to screen size, etc?

Right now the temporary fix is to manually truncate the message to an arbitrary 40 lines (which doesn't happen often), but a scroll bar, etc. would definitely be cleaner.

My code which breaks when using about 50 lines of text on a 720p monitor (not sure why anyone would still have 720p monitors...)

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(this, message, "Please confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
if (dr == DialogResult.No || dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return ResponseStatus.Fail;
return ResponseStatus.Success;
```

my hacky solution to truncate the message

```
var lines = message.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
if (lines.Count() > 40)
{
    //try removing blank line formatting
    lines = message.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    if (lines.Count() > 40)
    {
        var count = lines.Count();
        lines = lines.GetRange(0,40);
        lines.Add($"Prompt too long, {count - 40} lines have been removed. The rest will be logged.");
        logger.Info("Extra prompt lines: ");
        foreach (var line in lines.Skip(40))
            logger.Info(line);
    }
            
    message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
            
}
```

Comment: The bigger question is why you are placing 40+ lines into a standard message box, it's not designed for that.  Consider making your own dialog with a scrollbox as required

Comment: MessageBoxes are meant to present a short message, not to publish a book. A simple Form with a multiline TextBox / RichTextBox is very simple to build.